# Jasmine shared specs scoping issues with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tdd, jasmine

I'm attempting to DRY up some jasmine tests by extracting out shared examples.

```
@sharedExamplesForThing = (thing) ->
  beforeEach ->
    @thingy = new thing

  it "is neat", ->
    expect(@thingy.neat).toBeTruthy()


describe "widget with shared behavior", ->
  sharedExamplesForThing(-> new Widget)
```

This works nicely when everything is defined in one file.  The problems I'm encountering occur when I try to move the sharedExamples to a separate file.  I get `Can't find variable: sharedExamplesForThing ...`

So in the interest of debugging, I tried the following:

```
describe "widget with shared behavior", ->
  it "is acting like a meany", ->
    console.log sharedExamplesForThing
    expect(false).toBeTruthy()
  sharedExamplesForThing(-> new Widget)
```

In the `is acting like a meany` block, the log shows `sharedExamplesForThing` as `[Function]` but I still get the `Can't find variable` outside the `it`.  I feel like this might have something to do with a scoping issue outside of my current experience, but I could be completely wrong about that. What am I missing here?

(using rails, jasminerice, guard-jasmine)

Answer (score 2):

I found the piece on [shared examples from thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/9611103221/jasmine-and-shared-examples) really useful.

I implemented it in *coffeescript* as follows:

1) In some helper file that is loaded before all spec files:

```
window.FooSpec =
  sharedExamples: {}

window.itShouldBehaveLike = (->
  exampleName      = _.first(arguments)
  exampleArguments =
    _.select(_.rest(arguments), ((arg) => return !_.isFunction(arg)))
  innerBlock       = _.detect(arguments, ((arg) => return _.isFunction(arg)))
  exampleGroup     = FooSpec.sharedExamples[exampleName]

  if(exampleGroup)
    return describe(exampleName, (->
      exampleGroup.apply(this, exampleArguments)
      if(innerBlock) then innerBlock()
      )
    )
  else
    return it("cannot find shared behavior: '" + exampleName + "'", (->
      expect(false).toEqual(true)
      )
    )
)
```

2) For my specs:

(a) I can define a shared behaviour:

```
FooSpec.sharedExamples["had a good day"] = (->
  it "finds good code examples", ->
      expect(this.thoughtbot_spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
)
```

(b) And use it anywhere in some spec as:

```
itShouldBehaveLike("had a good day")
```

(Note: I am assuming the spec has defined `this.thoughtbot_spy` accordingly before the above line)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a top-level member variable in CoffeeScript it is assigned as a property of the global object (`window` in a Browser). So it generates the following JavaScript:

```
window.sharedExamplesForThing = ...;
```

That means that you can refer to it outside the file as `window.sharedExamplesForThing` or just `sharedExamplesForThing`. So what you are doing should work assuming the shared example file has been loaded before the spec file. I think the problem you have having is that the spec file is loaded first (because describe functions are run as the file is loaded whereas it functions are run after all the files have loaded). So you might need to adjust the load order, you could try putting your shared examples files in a `support` directory and then requiring this first.

Rather than assigning variables directly to the window object it may be better to set up a namespace to export your shared variables into (so that you don't clutter the global object):

```
window.MyNamespace = {}

MyNamespace.sharedExamplesForThing = ...
```

Then in your spec file you can refer to it as `MyNamespace.sharedExamplesForThing`.

I find it helpful to look at the generated JavaScript to try to understand how CoffeeScript exports variables between files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the blog post I wrote about how best to do shared examples. Hope this helps.

http://pivotallabs.com/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior/

Comment: Your blog post is highly incomplete. First, it misses the `sharedBehaviorForGameOf ` you are talking about in there, and secondly, I am having a test spec file which is almost 100% replica of yours, even to the exact hierarchy and having only one `it()` block per `describe()` block, and still, my "shared" variables are only visible to my first test and they are not referenceable in any other tests below the first one. I think few folks like me will appreciate if you complete your article and give a few tips on shared vars/functions. Besides that, you did a great job on the library, I love it.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am trying to use the shared vars in `runs()` blocks which consume the result of a real (non-mocked) AJAX call. Maybe it's a scoping issue, since obviously your vanilla examples work quite well.